# Finding the occurrence across multiple sheets but with a twist

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to find the number of sick leave of the workers per month. I know that can be achieved easily with `=Ifs ()`, but as you can see from this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the excel file]

the sheets may contain the data of other months (late December and early February in this case). There are 12 sheets in total, each contains one month of the year.

I want to write a function that can count the numbers of holidays given by "休息" for each month for each person.

The difficulty is that:

1. The roaster changes every month and cell position of each person changes, the other problem is:
2. As mentioned above, each sheet may contain data of other months, which implies the function has to refer to other sheets to count these leaves as well.

Can this be achieved with excel intrinsic functions or should this be done with VBA?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. If you need a dynamic function that loops through every worksheet (as you might add some sheets after creating the formula), you will have to use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

It is real difficult and lot of assumption, to try and understand the problem in unknown language and scanty details.  However the solution worked out based of a number of assumption and hope to offer only broad outline to be modified as real time solution according to actual layout of the working file

Assumptions:

1. Names are in column B
2. Names start at row 11
3. For trial only rows up to 35 are used
4. Days span from column D to AF (Approx)
5. Column AL is free and used for `Countif` formula
   For solution with excel formulas 
   Populate column  AL of all the monthly sheets with formula

   =COUNTIF(D11:AE11,"休息")

In a blank Sheet named “Main”  populate column B with list of all the names (may be starting from  row 11)
Now  Column C representing Month1  may be added with formula

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($B11,Sheet1!$B$11:$B$35,0)), "",INDEX(Sheet1!$AL$11:$AL$35,MATCH($B11,Sheet1!$B$11:$B$35,0),1))
```

Similarly Column D representing Month1  may be added with formula

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($B12,Sheet2!$B$11:$B$35,0)), "",INDEX(Sheet2!$AL$11:$AL$35,MATCH($B12,Sheet2!$B$11:$B$35,0),1))
```

And similarly add formula to all the 12 columns pointing towards 12 sheets in the workbook and the create a summation in next blank column
[Result Sheet Layout - Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPTPQ.jpg) and [Month sheets Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMDWt.jpg)

VBA solution

Add one blank sheet Named “MainVBA”  containing list of all the names in the column B starting from row 11 as done in sheet named  “Main”. Alternatively this employee list could be created by using dictionary object and collecting all unique names (case sensitive) from all the monthly sheets. For using this code please add reference to “Microsoft Scripting runtime”.  (VBA window – Tools – Reference)
Code:

```
Sub MakeList()
Dim MnWs As Worksheet, Ws As Worksheet
Dim Srw As Long, S1rw As Long
Dim Erw As Long, E1rw As Long
Dim Xname As String
Dim TRw As Long
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim Dict As Dictionary
Set MnWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainVBA")
Srw = 11                                          'Starting Row in Result sheet Named "MainVBA"
Erw = MnWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row   'Last Row in Result sheet Named "MainVBA"
MnWs.Range("B" & Srw & ":B" & Erw).ClearContents   ' Delete last row
Set Dict = New Dictionary

        'Get Names from monthly sheets
        For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "MainVBA" And Ws.Name <> "Main" Then   ' Consider all sheets Other than specified two having sick leave data
        S1rw = 11
        E1rw = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row        'Last Row in Month sheet
          For TRw = S1rw To E1rw
          Xname = Ws.Cells(TRw, "B").Value
            If Dict.Exists(Xname) = False Then
            'Debug.Print Ws.Name, TRw, Xname
            Dict.Add Xname, 1
            End If
          Next
        End If
        Next Ws

        'create list in Sheet "MainVBA" Column B from dictionary
        For Cnt = 0 To Dict.Count - 1
        MnWs.Cells(Cnt + 11, "B").Value = Dict.Keys(Cnt)
        Next
Set Dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Code for calculating sick leave count month wise. I used Range B1 to hold the string "休息" (as I refrained to tweak the regional settings etc) , it may be used directly in your VBA module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim MnWs As Worksheet, Ws As Worksheet
Dim Srw As Long, S1rw As Long, Scol As Long
Dim Erw As Long, E1rw As Long, Ecol As Long
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, Xname As String, ChineseStr As String
Dim TRw As Long, XRw As Long, Have As Boolean
Dim Rng As Range, Cnt As Long

Set MnWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainVBA")
ChineseStr = MnWs.Range("B1").Value   'May use string directly with quotes
Srw = 11                                          'Starting Row in Result sheet Named "MainVBA"
Erw = MnWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row   'Last Row in Result sheet Named "MainVBA"
Scol = 3                                          'Starting Col Month1 in Result sheet Named "MainVBA"
Ecol = 3 + 11                                     'End Col Month12 in Result sheet Named "MainVBA"

    For Rw = Srw To Erw
    Xname = MnWs.Cells(Rw, "B").Value
    Col = Scol
        For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "MainVBA" And Ws.Name <> "Main" Then   ' Consider all sheets Other thah specified two having Sick leave data
        S1rw = 11
        E1rw = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row        'Last Row in Month sheet
        XRw = 0
          For TRw = S1rw To E1rw
          If Ws.Cells(TRw, "B").Value = Xname Then
          XRw = TRw
          Exit For
          End If
          Next
        Cnt = 0
          If XRw > 0 Then
          'Debug.Print Xname, Ws.Name, TRw
          Set Rng = Ws.Range("D" & XRw & ":AF" & XRw)          ' Col D to AF condsidered having sick leave data
          Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ChineseStr)  'sum of month sick leave
          End If
        MnWs.Cells(Rw, Col).Value = Cnt
        Col = Col + 1
        End If
        Next Ws
    Next Rw
End Sub
```

To make this code working, it may be required to modify all the sheets details like sheets name, row, column details etc. Feel free to feedback if code is some where near to your objective and actual scenario.